# Regex for - 'A,B','C'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written this regex -

```
([\s]*'[A-Za-z0-9_: ]*[\,]*[\s]*[A-Za-z0-9_: ]*\'[\s]*)[\,]*
```

But this is not handling the input - 'A,B' 'C' - In this the comma is missing, still its a perfect match.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Can you provide some more examples of data you expect your regex to match, and what to exclude?

Comment: There are a lot of superfluous brackets and escaped characters. What are you trying to match?  Something like this? `'[A-Za-z0-9_: ](?:,[A-Za-z0-9_: ])*'` https://regex101.com/r/WXLATe/1

Comment: @PhonicUK Sure

'A','B','C','d','e','f','g','h','i' - just these letters will be replaced by Words (ex- Hello world)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried your regex on (https://regex101.com/r/L1ZOs0/1/) yet comma is not being matched

Comment: VALID CASES -    'A,B' ,'C',D','E'
INVALID CASES - 'A,B' ,'C',D''E'  ,  'A,B' ,'C',D','E  ,  'A,B' ,C',D','E'

User should not miss single quote or comma in between

Comment: @RizwanChaudhari In this valid part `'A,B' ,'C',D',` is there not a `'` missing before the `D'` ? https://regex101.com/r/UYFBnR/1

Answer (score 1):

After giving this more thought, I think what you want is something more like this:

`^(?<item>\'[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\')(\s*,(?&item))*\s*$`

<s>You're using an asterisk which will match zero instances. Try using + instead for the characters you want one or more of.</s>

Please provide other examples that you'd expect to match. For this specific case, the following would match, but is very rigid and specific:

`\'+[a-zA-Z]+\,\s*[a-zA-Z]+\'+\,\s*\'+[a-zA-Z]+\'+`

Edit:

This is more in line with what I *think* you want:

`^(\'[a-zA-Z]+(\,+\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*\'\s*\,*)*$`

Comment: In this case, 'A,B' ,'C' - I'll be needing comma at the end

Comment: Thanks for the regex, It solved 95% of the problem
The but if I put 'A' instead of 'A,B,' it fails

Comment: OK, that's a different case though. If you provide a series of examples of expected matches, I can adjust it. Like I  said, this was a pretty rigid match for this specific string. The more examples I have, the more generalized I can make the pattern.

Comment: Sure 
EXAMPLES :
VALID CASES - 'A,B' ,'C',D','E'   ||   'A' ,'C',D','E'   ||  'A' ,'C',D','E','A' ,'C',D','E' 'A' ,'C',D','E' ....
INVALID CASES - 'A,B' ,'C',D''E'  ||   'A,' ,'C',D','E   ||   ',B' ,C',D','E' 
User should not miss single quote or comma in between

Comment: ALSO - one of the input will be like - 'A,B' - two values in one quotes.
this should be preserved and if user puts - ',B'  || 'A,' - should be invalid

Comment: Do you intend to be missing leading single quotes in front of the "D" in the "Valid" examples?

Comment: And, regarding your last comment, I'm taking that to mean you only want a comma within the quotes if there's some character both preceding, and succeeding it?

Comment: Would you expect the values to be individually matched as tokens or just for the whole string to be valid or invalid?

Comment: Do you intend to be missing leading single quotes in front of the "D" in the "Valid" examples?
Sorry that was my mistake all values must be in single quotes.

Comment: And, regarding your last comment, I'm taking that to mean you only want a comma within the quotes if there's some character both preceding, and succeeding it?
- YES

Comment: Would you expect the values to be individually matched as tokens or just for the whole string to be valid or invalid?
- I want the whole string to be valid or invalid

Comment: If there should be a quote in front of the D this might work: `^(\'+[a-zA-Z]+(\,+\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*\'\s*\,*)*$`

Comment: It is almost working but - 'A,B', - In this the comma is extra and at the end which I want to be invalid .

Comment: I've updated my answer but here is the regex I think should work for you: `^(?<item>\'[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\')(\s*,(?&item))*\s*$`

You may want to switch ^ to \A and $ to \z in the context of your app, though.

Comment: As I am new to this, I would like to know what '?<item>' here stands for ? Because I am having pattern error for this. ( https://regex101.com/r/L1ZOs0/1/ )

Comment: Oops, didn't notice which section I was in. Haha. I gave you a PCRE, my js regex is rusty, but let me adjust. brb :)

Comment: What regex engine are you using? 
I am using javascript

Comment: please see this page - regex101.com/r/L1ZOs0/1